# Is anything "sensitive" stored in an iPhone Xcode project folder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, code-signing

I want to open source one of my iPhone applications (that I've already published in the iTunes store) but I obviously don't want to expose anything "sensitive" like provisioning certificates and code-signing keys, etc.  I'm guessing that stuff is merely *referenced* from the Xcode project folder (actually stored in my keychain elsewhere on disk) and if I were to share the entire project folder I'd be OK and nobody could hijack my identity with regards to the Apple iPhone Developer Program.  Would I be correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provisioning profile itself is stored elsewhere on your hard disk and copied to the device.  The code signing identity is stored in your Keychain. The only thing in the project file is the *name* of your identity certificate, not the certificate itself.

For posting or publishing open source code (or even sharing in a repository with other developers) you should just set the Code Signing Identity to the wildcard "iPhone Developer".

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine in regards to your Apple iPhone Developer Program identity. If you're releasing a build instead of the X-Code project folder, the only thing you may want to check is the embeddable provision file (though I did glance at it quickly and it doesn't look like it contains any sensitive data).