# How to make sure an xcode project does not contain private keys

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I have an xcode (iOS) project I'd like to open source, 
but after all the signing activties I'm not sure where 
my private keys and certificates are.

How can I make sure that I don't reveal private information?

Comment: Found a possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960893/is-anything-sensitive-stored-in-an-iphone-xcode-project-folder?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

u can drag ur app to "App Scanner",It will automatically detect and display the results.

Comment: I didn't find App Scanner in Google, do you have a link?